# tryLock functionlaity not working for .txt files

Tags: java, file, nio

If I manually open .txt file and then executed code to check if file is open or not. It always says file is not opened. But same code works as expected for any MS Office(.doc, .xls, .ppt).

Here is the code snippet:

```
        File file = new File("F:\\abc.txt");
        FileChannel channel = null;
        FileLock lock = null;

        try {

            channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
            // Get an exclusive lock on the whole file
            try {
                lock = channel.tryLock();
                if (lock != null) {
                    System.out.println("Lock acquired on file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    lock.release();
                    System.out.println("Lock released from closed file.");
                    System.out.println("Closing the channel of closed file.");
                }

                channel.close();
            }
            catch (OverlappingFileLockException | IOException e) {
                // File is open by someone else
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // File is open by someone else
        }
```

Each time, .txt file acquires lock even though same file is opened (which is not same behavior for MS Office files ).

Is there any other way to test whether file is opened/used by other process ?

Comment: What are you opening the file with?

Comment: both way its not working: either by manually opening that is double click on it nor thru code  `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`

Comment: What do you mean by "opened"? Notepad for example doesn't lock the text file.

Comment: I tries to open it with notepad, notepad++ even with MS Office Word..

Comment: If you use a program which does not lock the file its legit to acquire the lock in java. For example if I open a text file in notepad, I can delete the file and windows wont complain. You have to open the file in a program which actually locks the file.

Comment: @morpheus05 : Is there any other way to check if any file is opened or not?

Comment: As I said in my answer: Rewrite your program in a way it keeps the lock until it closes. Or write a second one which acquire a lock and then run your first program.

Comment: I my answer solved you problem please accept the answer, otherwise ask further question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that most programs in windows do not lock the text file. For example if you open a text file with notepad, you can delete it. That means, notepad does not acquire a lock and so you can acquire the lock in your java program.

For your test you have to use a program which actually locks a text file or rewrite your program it locks a file until you close the program. Then you can launch your program twice.

Comment: Thankx for your suggestion. I tried to add exclusive lock, but then user won't be able to edit this file. Is their any other way except adding lock to find target file is opened?

Comment: The point of a lock is that the user cannot edit the file. If you want to know if the file is open not with conventional means. But if your question is: How can I detect modifications of my file? I suggest to look at the new file io api, I think there is a whatcher class implemented.